# Detecting whether a connectionless Unix Domain Socket has no receiver

Tags: ipc, unix-socket

I'm working on the design of a multi-process server which will need to be able to send connected sockets to sibling processes. I plan to do this with unix domain sockets, but I don't want to keep open O(n^2) connections to make them all connected to each other, so I was thinking of using connectionless (i.e. SOCK_DGRAM) UDS (to avoid overhead of connecting and disconnecting every time).

What I'm concerned about is what will happen if one of the processes crashes, and is no longer receiving messages on its UDS socket?

Will the sender block, simply buffer the data in the kernel, give an unambiguous error about the problem (nobody receiving), something else?

Essentially, I guess the problem boils down to 'How do I tell if there exists a (running) process which has bound a given UDS?'

Answer (score 3):

If you try to `sendto` an AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM socket that does not exist, the sendto(2) call should fail with ENOENT.  So as long as you check the error return values of your sendto calls, and handle them properly, everything should be fine.

There are race conditions if you send to a socket just as the process that has it open is crashing (and closing it), which will result in lost messages, so you need to be aware of that too.

Comment: If the target process bind()s the UDS and then crashes, won't it leave the 'socket file' laying around on the filesystem? Would that cause the kernel to simply buffer the message, and eventually block/EWOULDBLOCK once that buffer was full?

Comment: The path used for an AF_UNIX socket does not have anything to do with the filesystem or any files anywhere -- its just a string that is limited in length to the same maximum length as a filesystem path.

Comment: Are you sure? All the examples I've seen use unlink().